LightGBM binary classifier: how can I know which values of categorical feature offer the most discrimination?
I am familiar with using methods such as lgb.plot_split_value_histogram to investigate the most used splitting points along numerical features. Is there an equivalent for categorical features in lightgbm (xgboost?). I can think of one hot encoding my categorical features and checking the splitting points in the same way as a numerical feature but the performance will take a hit and the interpretation may shift. This expectation is due to the way LightGBM exploits categorical features (see https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/614855/53866).
